# How to access Entity Manager within a service in spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I've googled so many times for how to access entity manager in spring boot, and did what posts said, but it didn't work. I want to access Entity Manager so that i can do some custom query operation. Here i defined the custom interface in a dependent package named 'customrepository':

```
public interface PostRepositoryCustom {
     void refresh(Post post);
}
```

Then I implemented this interface in another package named 'customrepositoryimpl':

```
public class CustomPostRepositoryImpl implements PostRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public void refresh(Post post) {
    em.refresh(post);       
  }
}
```

Finally, I defined a standard repository interface which extends 'CrudRepository' and the custom repository:

```
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post,Long>,PostRepositoryCustom {}
```

Every steps i followed What i googled and Official Documents, BUT when i run my application, i get this:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'postRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.demo.customrepository.PostRepositoryCustom.refresh(com.example.demo.model.Post)! No property refresh found for type Post!
```

Why? Anyone tell me where should i correct my mistakes?

Comment: Do you have a repo in which we can take a look at?

Comment: Why do your repositories have no annotations? Maybe you could annotate `PostRepositoryCustom` with `@NoRepositoryBean` and `CustomPostRepositoryImpl` with `@Repository`. Also the reason why `postRepository` cannot be created is because it does not povide a default implementation. How is spring supposed to know what to do when `refresh` is being invoked? The `CrudRepository` is known to spring, unlike `PostRepositoryCustom`

Answer (score 0):

Spring cannot locate the beans, so try annotate with @Repository

```
@Repository
public class CustomPostRepositoryImpl implements PostRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public void refresh(Post post) {
    em.refresh(post);       
  }
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post,Long>{

}
```